# Oracle SQL query to get columns which has values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have user table with 100+ columns where some of the columns has null values depending on user type in the table. I am looking for SQL query to list the rows which has values in columns for particular user type. I have seen certain examples but those queries has specific column name in condition. In my situation, i have many columns that can be null. Can some one help me with the query?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Oracle Statistics enabled, (i belive they are always enabled in 11g), you can use the NUM_DISTINCT column of user_tab_columns:

Generate testing table and populate:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING ( 
JOE VARCHAR2(200),
FREDDY VARCHAR2(200),
CAR NUMBER );

INSERT INTO TESTING VALUES ('1', 'x', NULL);
INSERT INTO TESTING VALUES ('b', '2', NULL);
COMMIT;

ANALYZE TABLE TESTING COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

The Query you need:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TESTING' AND NUM_DISTINCT <> 0
```